# does Mobile phones have IP address

Tags: java-me, mobile, ip-address, gprs, lwuit

Hi All
Can you tell me if the mobile phones have IP address.. (I know we have it if we connect our phones to Wi-Fi)..but if we connect via GPRS.. if the answer is yes..how can I find it..I am doing the coding in J2ME and LUWIT...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect through GPRS then no your mobile does not have an unique IP address.

Comment: tx a lot Harry..does the answer remain the same for 3G as well?