# Is home address is the address obtained at first time when the mobile node joins a network?

Tags: mobile, ip

In Mobile IP, Is home address is the address obtained at first time when the mobile node joins a network?

Answer (score 0):

> Is home address is the address
>   obtained at first time when the mobile
>   node joins a network?

If you are talking about IP address then ***NO***.

Mobiles does not have any IP address. It uses proxy.

Comment: @sangita: read this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623163/does-mobile-phones-have-ip-address